# How to construct the final action for a supergravity theory $N = 1$ in 4D?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action, supergravity

I am trying to understand the basics of supergravity theory $N = 1$ in 4D, which combines supersymmetry and general relativity. I know that the theory involves a spin 2 field whose quantum is the graviton, and a spin 3/2 field whose quantum is the gravitino. The number of gravitino fields is equal to the number of supersymmetries.

I have learned how to write the Einstein-Hilbert action for the graviton field $g_{\mu\nu}$, and the Rarita-Schwinger action for the gravitino field $\psi_\mu^\alpha$. These actions are given by
$$S_{EH} = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} R,$$
$$S_{RS} = -\frac{i}{2}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \bar{\psi}_\mu \gamma_5 \gamma_\nu D_\rho \psi_\sigma,$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $g$ is the determinant of the metric, $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol, $\bar{\psi}_\mu$ is the Dirac adjoint of the gravitino, $\gamma_5$ and $\gamma_\nu$ are the gamma matrices, and $D_\rho$ is the covariant derivative.

However, I am not sure how to construct the final action for the supergravity theory $N = 1$ in 4D. I have read that there are some additional terms that arise from imposing general covariance and local supersymmetry, such as the torsion term and the Chern-Simons term. I have also read that there is an antisymmetric potential $B_{\mu\nu}$ that is coupled to the gravitino field by a gauge invariant term.

Can someone explain to me how to derive these additional terms? What are the physical meanings and implications of these terms and couplings? How can I write the final action for the supergravity theory $N = 1$ in 4D in a compact and elegant way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To which dimensional space does "your" theory refer? 4D , 5D or 11D etc. ?

Comment: @FredericThomas In 4D

Comment: https://saalburg.aei.mpg.de/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2017/03/samtleben.pdf